# Video lag with both OSMC and OpenOlec

Tags: pi-3, video, osmc

When I try to play certain videos on my RPi3, it starts lagging and can't play it fluently.  It often pauses, so they are unwatchable.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhbRn.png) of the video's encoding.

My `config.txt` is :

```
OSMC:
gpu_mem_1024=256  
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1  
disable_overscan=1
start_x=1  
disable_splash=1
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi  
gpu_mem_256=112  
sdtv_aspect=1  
dtparam=gpio_in_pin=18  
gpu_mem_512=144  
dtparam=gpio_out_pin=17
```

Here is [my OpenOlec config](http://pastebin.com/Dhj3b4a7).

Do I need to change frequency settings to something else?

Any clues?

Comment: Where are the videos stored - on the SD card, on USB storage, on a local network, or on the internet somewhere?

Comment: Server, connected by inbuild wi-fi